# Call a function and Insert in MySQL Parallel in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, sails.js

Is there anyway how to insert data in parallel from an external data source? Meaning I have multiple APIs/Endpoint that provide similar dataset that will be inserted in a database.

For example:

[image]

My current code is looping through each API and saving it to the database. My target behavior is the image above and hopefully dynamic. Meaning I can add multiple Endpoints and can insert in parallel when calling my insert function.

Comment: mysql most certainly supports parallel data modifications out of the box via multiple connections, so it is really up to your application logic to achieve it.

Comment: Hi @Shadow. Thanks for replying. My problem is how to implement this kind of logic. Calling the insert function in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

To prepare to write the code you will be wise to tool up a version of the MySQL API in node that [works with async/await](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Promise-Wrapper.md#es7-async-await) (that is, a Promise-based API).

Then tool up to use a mysql connection pool. You can limit the total number of connections in a pool. That is wise because too many connections can overwhelm your MySQL server.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise')

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'host',
  user: 'redacted',
  database: 'redacted',
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 6,
  queueLimit: 0
})

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}
```

Then write each API access operation as an async function with a loop in it. Something like this gets a connection to use, even for multiple sequential queries, for each API operation.

```js
async function apiOne(pool) {
  while (true) {
    const result = await (api_operation)
    connection = await pool.getConnection()
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(whatever)
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(whatever_else)
    connection.release()
    await sleep(1000)  // wait one second
  }
}
```

Do `getConnection()` inside the loop, not outside it. `Pool.getConnection()` is very fast because it re-uses existing connections. Doing it inside the loop allows your pool to limit the number of simultaneous connections.

The `sleep()` function is optional of course. You can use it to control how fast the loop runs.

Write as many of these functions as you need. This is a good way to handle multiple APIs because the code for each one is isolated in its own function.

Finally, use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to run all your async functions concurrently.

```js
const concurrents = []
concurrents.push (apiOne(pool))
concurrents.push (apiTwo(pool))
concurrents.push (apiThree(pool))
Promise.all (concurrents).then()  /* run all the ApiXxx functions */
```

Beware, this sample code is dangerously oversimplified. It lacks any error or exception handling, which you need in long-running code.